# Exclude 3rd party libraries, it's class & sub class from ProGuard with Android using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, obfuscation, android-proguard

Getting following error when I try to exclude 3rd party libraries in the ProGuard.

It is compiling, if i add "-dontwarn com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager" in the proguard-project.txt,
but getting crash when try to run.

Basically I want to NOT to obfuscate  "com.ak.systemservice. core.security.FuncManager" class in jar or entire jar, and want to use "com.ak.systemservice. core.security.FuncManager"in my activity. Thanks in advance.

Here are the errors:

> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.os.ServiceManager
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.os.ServiceManager
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService$Stub
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService$Stub
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager$1
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager$1
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService
>
> [2016-01-26 17:00:27 - MyApp] Warning: com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager: can't find referenced class android.security.FuncService

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by avoiding this class from getting minified. Add this to your proguard file,

```
-keep class com.ak.** { *; }
-keep interface com.ak.** { *; }
-keep enum com.ak.** { *; }
```

Or you can keep individual class also. Like this,

```
-keep class com.ak.systemservice.core.security.FuncManager
```

Comment: Not yet! Thank you for follow-up! Before going to this step, getting JNI native callback error, and the app is crashed! Somehow, proguard is striping JNI method names and causing crash. How can I make sure that ProGuard is not strip out JNI? How can I keep specific JNI callback method in away from ProGuard?

Thanks,

Comment: By default JNI native functions won't get obfuscated. But, if you are using it in your code and your code get obfuscated, that may create problems. Change the above code and add it to pro guard file after include your package name to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet! Thank you for follow-up! Before going to this step, getting JNI native callback error, and the app is crashed! Somehow, proguard is striping JNI method names and causing crash. How can I make sure that ProGuard is not strip out JNI? How can I keep specific JNI callback method in away from ProGuard?

Thanks,